# range function doesn't work in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am super advanced in Python and trying to get this right..
"Implement a program that requests an integer n from the user and prints on the screen
the squares of all numbers from 0 up to, but not including, n"

```
x=input('enter a number:')
def square(x):
    result=x**2
    return result

for i in range(0,x):
    print(i)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: "I am super advanced in Python" - if you were joking, it didn't work. Tone doesn't come through well in text. If you were serious, you have a severely overinflated opinion of your skills.

Comment: Wait, you are super advanced in Python and you are asking a Python 101 question?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which part of this isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I am NOT advanced in Python! Haha I did a typo

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try this code:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
for i in range(0, int(x)):
    print (i**2)
```

Issues in the question:

1. X is not converted to an integer
2. The `square` function is unused and can be replaced with `**2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `x` is not an integer, it is a string. In this case you are asking Python to count up to something which, as far as Python is concerned, has no numerical value. Adding an `int()` statement and printing the correct thing should do the trick.

```
x = int(input('enter a number:'))
def square(x):
    result = x**2
    return result

for i in range(0,x):
    print(square(i))
```

Comment: Please don't say that the problem is the programmer. People aren't defective. What we have here is an opportunity to help someone increase their general programming and Python skills.

Comment: Apologies, I meant it as a joke but I see that it was unnecessary

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: One more time, sorry.. I am NOT advanced is what I meant in the question. I was tired so I did a typo :) thanks for the help everyone